# bindAll() seems not to work in backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I have View listening for an "add" event on a Collection.  When the handler fires, the context is the Collection, even though I used _.bindAll() to bind it to the View.  Is this a bug, or am I not understanding how this works? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elplatt/eE4ws/)

```
V = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.collection.on('add', this.onAdd);
        _.bindAll(this, 'onAdd');
    },
    onAdd: function () { console.log(this); }
});
c = new Backbone.Collection();
v = new V({collection:c});
c.add(new Backbone.Model());
```

Outputs:

```
e.Collection {length: 1, models: Array[1], _byId: Object, _events: Object, on: function…}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the bindAll method before the binding to collection statement
This should work:

```
V = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function (options) {
    _.bindAll(this, 'onAdd');
    this.collection.on('add', this.onAdd);

},
onAdd: function () { console.log(this); }
```

});

**UPDATE:**
It's possible not to use the _.bindAll method by applying the context in the .on() method

```
this.collection.on('add', this.onAdd, this);
```

Comment: This is correct.  `_.bindAll` is replacing `onAdd` with a new function, when you pass `this.onAdd` before calling it, you are passing a reference to the old, unbound, version.

Comment: Also, a better solution is just to pass the context on the on declaration. i.e, `this.collection.on('add', this.onAdd, this);`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when your call `this.collection.on('add', this.onAdd);` first an event is bound to the `onAdd` function with no context (this = collection at trigger time) and calling `_.bindAll(this, 'onAdd');` doesn't override it.

Try to change the order :

```
    _.bindAll(this, 'onAdd');
    this.collection.on('add', this.onAdd);
```